# mq_send and mq_receive seem blocked - no transmission seems to happen

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I am writing a producer/consumer app where one thread writes to the message queue while other consumes/reads from it, but it seems as if both the `mq_send()` and `mq_receive()` are blocked hence no transmission takes place.

In other words, I don't see the prints from either `Transmit` or `Receive` functions i.e `Received buffer: %s` or `Sent...`

```
#define MAX_MESSAGES      10
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE     180
#define MSG_BUFF_SIZE     MAX_BUFF_SIZE + 10
#define QUEUE_PERMISSIONS 0660

static pthread_t rxHdlr;
static pthread_t txHdlr;

static void* Transmit(void* arg);
static void* Receive(void* arg);

char readBuffer [MSG_BUFF_SIZE];
char writeBuffer [MSG_BUFF_SIZE];

#define NAME   "/sp-sample"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

    if (pthread_create(&rxHdlr, NULL, Receive, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Fail to create a server thread!\n");
    }

    if (pthread_create(&txHdlr, NULL, Transmit, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf ("fail to create a client thread\n");
    }

    pthread_join(rxHdlr, 0);
    pthread_join(txHdlr, 0);
}
```

Consumer

```
static void* Receive(void* arg)
{
    struct mq_attr attr;
    static mqd_t mqd;       

    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    mq_unlink(NAME);

    if ((mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0644, &attr)) == -1) 
    {
        printf ("mq_open failed in UartRx: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit (1);
    }


    while(1)
    {
        int iret = mq_receive(mqd, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), NULL);
        if (iret == -1)
        {   
            printf ("Errno: %d\n", errno);
        }
        printf ("Received buffer: %s\n", readBuffer);
    }
}
```

Producer

```
static void* Transmit(void* arg)
{
    int iRet;
    mqd_t mqd;  
    char buffer[100] = "TX data!";

    if ((mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_WRONLY)) == -1) 
    {
        printf ("TX MqOpen failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit (1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if (mq_send (mqd, buffer, strlen (buffer) + 1, 0) == -1) 
        {
            perror ("Client unable to send message to server"); 
        }
        printf ("Sent...\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: It would really help if you provide complete code so that others can copy it exactly as shown to repro the problem. The code shown is almost there but missing all the header includes (and is broken up into sections which makes it slightly more tedious to copy). FWIW, I added the missing code, ran it and it worked fine for me. Suggest you do a bit more debugging. Have you confirmed that the threads are running? That is, use a debugger or print something when the thread starts.

Comment: There is one race condition in your code but it should lead to different symptoms than you have described. You create the mq in one thread but have no explicit synchronisation to ensure that the create happens before the other thread attempts to open it. And no, the order of `pthread_create` does not guarantee the order that the threads run in.

Comment: Just a guess ... Receiver is opening with `O_RDONLY | O_CREAT` and producer is opening with `O_WRONLY`. Do you want: Receiver: `O_RDONLY` and Producer: `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT`???

Comment: I put the code separately for visibility reasons. I could add header files as well but I restarted the machine and ran the app just to see Consumer thread runs first and it errors out saying `No such file or directory`, which probably is cause Consumer thread hasn't yet run to create a message queue. Would you use synchronization mechanism like a semaphore to ensure Consumer thread runs first and invoke `sem_post` after message queue is created so Producer thread can run and use the existing message queue?

Comment: @CraigEstey does message queue creation matter whether it's in the producer or consumer? I believe they just need to be synchronized to ensure the other thread opens the existing queue only after it's been created

Comment: It's kinda usual to create producer-consumer queue instances before any thread can attempt to access them, eg. by creating the queue and passing it to the threads as create arguments.

Comment: I always pair the `O_CREAT` with the writer. But, your program works if you put (e.g.) `sleep(1)` after the first `pthread_create` [to allow the creation to happen]. The clean way is to use a sync variable (set to 1 in one thread and tested for in the other). Or, as Martin suggested, create the queues before invoking any `pthread_create`

Comment: yeah I was thinking of using semaphore but it makes more sense to create the message queue prior to invoking threads since they don't necessarily have to be done inside the thread anyways. I tried what @MartinJames suggested and it works now. Thanks :)